# Is AppendHeader exactly the same as AddHeader?

Tags: asp.net

We use ASP.Net 4.0. In our code we regularly use `Response.AddHeader("x", "y")`. Is this exactly the same as `Response.AppendHeader("x", "y")`? I read that AppendHeader only exists for compatibility with classic ASP, which we do not use.

Can we, without any concerns, replace AddHeader with AppendHeader?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are the same, so yes, you can replace `HttpResponse.AddHeader` with `HttpResponse.AppendHeader`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> AddHeader is the same as AppendHeader
>   and is provided only for compatibility
>   with earlier versions of ASP. With
>   ASP.NET, use AppendHeader.

A quick peek with [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) confirms that `HttpResponse.AddHeader` just calls `HttpResponse.AppendHeader`.

Answer (score 13):

They are not the same (at least for `HttpListenerContext`).

Here is the test:

```
ctx.Response.AddHeader("a", "b");
ctx.Response.AddHeader("a", "c");
```

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
a: c
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 16:42:01 GMT
```

And now like this:

```
ctx.Response.AddHeader("a", "b");
ctx.Response.AppendHeader("a", "c");
```

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
a: b
a: c
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 16:53:29 GMT
```

Comment: I tried it on a page and they both give the same result `a: b, c`

Comment: aspx pages may behave diffrently. My very first line says "at least for HttpListenerContext" I didn't check for others, pages, web services, web api and so on, may behave slightly different from each other.  System.Web.HttpResponse is diffrent than System.Net.HttpListenerContext. Different namespace. My answer was more for "awareness" I could say?

Comment: I know, that's why I specifically mentioned "on a page", just for additional info :) (coz I first thought it would be the same on pages, but it's not)